# in Angular6 service is not loading

Tags: angular

[image: error]

i just started learning angular everything was going good as soon before i added service(dish.service.ts) to my project.

this is the error
 ./src/app/services/dish.service.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

dish.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { Dishes } from '../shared/dishes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {

  constructor() { 
    getDishes():Dish[]{
        return DISHES;
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platformbrowser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'hammerjs';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { DishDetailsComponent } from './dish-details/dish-details.component';
import { DishService } from './services/dish.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    DishDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
   MatButtonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [ DishService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why you have dishService in providers [] you already declared it at root level so you don’t need to declare in your module file

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to register services in `app.module.ts -> providers:[]` because you are using angular 6 and it's have features now like `providedIn: 'root'`.

Second you added your function in `getDishes()` in constructor, so remove from there and add it after constructor like,

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {

   constructor() {}

   getDishes(): Dish[]{
     return DISHES;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which you can use your service though, depends on your requirement
how you want to handle

1. Put service in `app.module.ts`

By adding the service in the providers array it means in your application you want to maintain a single instance of the service and you want to inject one service into another

eg:

```js
//import the service
providers: [yourseriviceName]
//this would create a single instance also don't added
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})  
// as it is not need .
```

2. If you want to import in only in your component and want multiple instances of the service

service.ts:

```js
export class dummyService {
    constructor(parameters) {
        
    }

    yourMethod(){
        return //Something
    }
}
```

component.ts

import your service as well

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dummy',
    styleUrls: ['dummy.component.sass'],
    templateUrl: 'dummy.component.html',
    providers:[dummyService]
})

export class yourComponentName {
    constructor(private dummyservice:dummyService) {
    }

    //Acces your service via
    this.dummyservice.yourMethod()
}
```

3. When you want to inject one service in another service:

```js
//import injectable from angular core
//import your service which you want to inject

//Note ensure you import injectable first and then your service
@injectable()
export class dummyService {
    constructor(parameters) {

    }

    yourMethod(){
        return //Something
    }
}
```

Coming to your problem it is problem with your method it is in the constructor, to give you a better overview when you create a class in typescript the constructor is executed first, and then other angular lifecycle hooks
so please refer to my second point and keep your method outside of the constructor and access it as I have shown in `component.ts`.